# How to make a pop window in php

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I need to add a popup window in my index.php file .The pop up window should appear on the screen whenever I click the user src. Here is my index.php file.

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="../dummy1.php"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> </a></li>
        <li><a href="../dummy1.php"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> </a></li>
        <li><a href="../dummy1.php"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> </a></li>
        <li><a href="../dummy1.php"><i class="fa fa-plug"></i> </a></li>
        
    </ul> 
    
</div>
    <div class="main_content">
        <div style="width: 100%">
        <div class="header" style="align-items: center;">
             <a >Anomaly Monitoring Dashboard</a>
             <div> 
             <a href="#" name="insert" id="insert" > <img src="../assets/images/logo.png" width="35" height="35" style="vertical-align:middle"/> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></a>
             <a href="logout.php" style="margin-left: 2em;"><i class="fa fa-toggle-left"></i> logout</a>
            </div>
    
         </div>
</div>
        <div class="info">
          
      </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

I have found that the following link can use for my function.
https://www.softaox.info/ajax-popup-view-add-and-update-data-using-php-mysql/

But the issue is I couldnot merge these two codes due to the `styles` whenever I changed the styles(bootstrap links) my index.php fonts and sizes are changing. Can someone help me to merge these two codes without getting any issue to my original interface>

Answer (score 0):

when you use their styles, right click the popup and click inspect. Here you can see which styles the popup actually needs. Take those styles and put them in your own stylesheet.

Comment: Can you place a example here?